# How to calculate the power consumption in kwh using a prometheus query

Tags: prometheus, promql, pdu

I have this Prometheus query that i am using to calculate the power consumption of apc PDUs in KWH,

```
sum(sum_over_time((rPDU2DeviceStatusPower_gauge{site=~"$site"})[$__range] /100 ) / count_over_time(rPDU2DeviceStatusPower_gauge{site=~"$site"}[$__range]) * ($__range/3600)) by (site)
```

i am visualizing this in pie chart that why i am grouping by site name of each pdu.

my collect interval is 5min

the metric rPDU2DeviceStatusPower_gauge return the power consumption of the pdu load in hundredths of kilowatts, that's why i am dividing by 100

can you tell me if this query is correct ?

What i tried : the query above

What i am expecting : well, to get the correct value in kwh

Comment: What do you mean "can we tell if it correct"? Have you run it? Does it return expected output?

Comment: yes i run it, but the values that i am getting in kwh seems wrong

Comment: What i mean by if it is correct is to know "if the equation that i am using to calculate the value in kwh is correct ?"

Comment: As you can see in my answer, you query seems mostly fine. If you have doubts about values: create new panel, put query `rPDU2DeviceStatusPower_gauge{site=~"$site"}` and switch `Table view`. You'll see all the values of metric, and could verify result value manually.

Comment: Also remember, since you gather metrics only once 5 minutes, you'll get estimation of power consumption, quite possibly a rough one.

Answer (score 0):

```
sum_over_time(
        rPDU2DeviceStatusPower_gauge{site=~"$site"}[$__range] /100 
    )
    / count_over_time(
        rPDU2DeviceStatusPower_gauge{site=~"$site"}[$__range]
    )
```

can be boiled down to `avg_over_time(rPDU2DeviceStatusPower_gauge{site=~"$site"}[$__range])/100`.

So, your resulting query would be:

```
sum(
    avg_over_time(rPDU2DeviceStatusPower_gauge{site=~"$site"}[$__range])
       / 100 * ($__range/3600)
) by (site)
```

If `rPDU2DeviceStatusPower_gauge` reports reports in hundreds of kW, then result should be estimation of power consumption in kWh.

Also, if `rPDU2DeviceStatusPower_gauge` is generated by your side, consider [Best practices](https://prometheus.io/docs/practices/naming/) regarding naming and units of your metrics. If it possible at least move from hundreds kW to kW.

Comment: the unit that i am using is Energy >> Kwh

Comment: @Sarahack, sorry, my mistake. Corrected.